# Why different array length output in concurrent golang programming?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm writing a simple program in golang for concurrency test and don't understand different output of `capitalized` **array size** every time!

```
data := []rune{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
var capitalized []rune

capIt := func(r rune) {
    capitalized = append(capitalized, unicode.ToUpper(r))
    fmt.Printf("%c done!\n", r)
}

fmt.Printf("Before: %c\n", capitalized)
for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
    go capIt(data[i])
}
time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
fmt.Printf("After: %c\n", capitalized)
```

Outputs:

> b done! a done! d done! c done! After: [D B C A]

> a done! d done! c done! b done! After: [D B A]

> d done! a done! c done! b done! After: [B]

> d done! a done! c done! b done! After: [A B C]

> d done! b done! a done! c done! After: [B C]

Comment: Concurrency means (more or less) that things run in parallel. In your case you are running goroutines that run in parallel and modify the same data at the same time. Without some kind of synchronization they will overwrite and corrupt the result of each other. So you have just discovered how NOT to do it.

Comment: @jurez But all convertin is done. `d done! a done! c done! b done!`

Comment: In the code, `capitalized` slice is shared among multiple goroutines. Concurrent access to shared data without proper synchronization can lead to data races. This can result in different output sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Go: Data Race Detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector)

---

You have data races.

```
$ go run -race racer.go
Before: []
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c000012018 by goroutine 8:
  main.main.func1()
      racer.go:14 +0xc4
  main.main.func2()
      racer.go:20 +0x3e

Previous read at 0x00c000012018 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      racer.go:14 +0x44
  main.main.func2()
      racer.go:20 +0x3e

Goroutine 8 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      racer.go:20 +0x199

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      racer.go:20 +0x199
==================
a done!
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c000012018 by goroutine 9:
  main.main.func1()
      racer.go:14 +0xc4
  main.main.func2()
      racer.go:20 +0x3e

Previous write at 0x00c000012018 by goroutine 10:
  main.main.func1()
      racer.go:14 +0xc4
  main.main.func2()
      racer.go:20 +0x3e

Goroutine 9 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      racer.go:20 +0x199

Goroutine 10 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      racer.go:20 +0x199
==================
d done!
b done!
c done!
After: [B C]
Found 2 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

---

racer.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    data := []rune{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
    var capitalized []rune

    capIt := func(r rune) {
        capitalized = append(capitalized, unicode.ToUpper(r))
        fmt.Printf("%c done!\n", r)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Before: %c\n", capitalized)
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        go capIt(data[i])
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("After: %c\n", capitalized)
}
```